# Assembly basics - output not working

Tags: assembly

I desperately need help with repairing output in my program. I'm supposed to have a working program by tommorow in assembly. I've tried everything I could think of and it's still not working. I'm supposed to read an input (few words) and output should be number of words with same lenght, for example:

```
input: hello world my name is dummy
output: 3 2 1
```

It should all be simulated on IO. Here's my code, please be considerate, I saw assembly yeasterday for the first time.

```
.h8300s
.equ syscall,0x1FF00            ;simulated IO area
.equ PUTS,0x0114                ;kod PUTS
.equ GETS,0x0113                ;kod GETS

;-------------------[ PROCEDURY ]--------------------------------

nacti_slovo:
        MOV.B   @ER2, R6H       ;nacteni prvniho znak
        CMP.B   #0xA, R6H         
        BEQ     uloz_slovo      ;kdyz je na konci retezce, tak skocim do ukladani
        CMP.B   #' ', R6H       
        BEQ     uloz_slovo      ;kdyz je znak mezera, tak ulozit
        ADD.L   #1,ER3          ;navyseni pocitadla o 1
        INC.L   #1, ER2         ;posunuti ukazatele ER2 na dalsi znak
        BRA     nacti_slovo     ;zopakovani smycky

uloz_slovo:
        MOV.L   #POLE, ER4      ;nacteni adresy pole
        ADD.L   #-1, ER3
        ADD.L   ER3, ER4        ;posunuti na spravny byte
        MOV.B   @ER4, R5L       ;nacteni hodnoty z ER4 do R5L
        ADD.B   #1,R5L          ;navyseni poctu slov o 1
        mov.b   R5L,@ER4        ;ulozeni poctu slov zpet do pameti

        CMP.B   #0xA, R6H         
        BEQ     konec_vstupu    ;pokud je konec retezce, program se ukonci
        XOR.L   ER3,ER3         ;vynulovani pocitadla, pokud nejsme na konci retezce
        INC.L   #1, ER2         ;posunuti v retezci o znak dal
        BRA     nacti_slovo     ;skok zpet do smycky

konec_vstupu:
        rts

;----------------[ DATOVA SEKCE ]-------------------------

.data    

TEXT:   .space 96               ;input 
POLE:   .asciz "0\n\r"              ;output

        .align 2                ;zarovnani adresy
cTest:  .long POLE      
cVstup: .long TEXT              ;parametricky blok input

stck:
        .align 1
        .space 200

;----------------[ HLAVNI PROGRAM ]-------------------------

.text           
.global _start

_start:

        mov.l #stck,ER7

        xor.l ER1,ER1
        xor.l ER2,ER2
        xor.l ER3,ER3           ;vynulovani registru    
        xor.l ER4,ER4
        xor.l ER5,ER5

        mov.w #GETS,R0          ;24bitovy GETS
        mov.l #cVstup,ER1       ;adr. param. bloku do ER1
        jsr @syscall

        MOV.L #TEXT, ER2    ;presunu odkaz na zacatek textu

        jsr nacti_slovo     

        mov.w   #PUTS,R0        ;24bit PUTS
        mov.l   #cTest,ER1      ;add. param. block to ER1 
        jsr     @syscall

end:    bra end

.end
```

Comment: What assembly/processor is it?

Comment: It's simulated on H8S

Comment: It's not look like human written code isn't it? where do you compile it? Are you using NASM?

Comment: I wrote it in HEW (High-Performace Embedded Workshop), but as I wrote, I can't really understand assembler, so it might look stupid for someone who understands it.

Comment: So what about it isn't working? Where do things go wrong, and in what way?  (btw, English labels and comments would've been nice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, here's my understanding of what you're trying to do:

You've got an array `POLE` that contains the counts for each word length. The count for words of length 1 is stored at offset 0, the count for words of length 2 at offset 1, and so on.
You start the counts at `'0'`, thereby automatically getting a printable count as long as none of them go beyond `'9'`.

Then why is `POLE` declared as `.asciz "0\n\r"`? To be large enough to handle words lengths of 1..9 characters it would need to be `.asciz "000000000\n\r"`. The way it's currently declared you'll end up overwriting the NULL-terminator if you find any word of length 4.

Another things is that, according to your example, it seems like the counts should be printed in descending order. I don't see you doing that anywhere.
If you fixed the `POLE` declaration and used the words from your example you should get the output `020130000`. Perhaps that's good enough(?).

Comment: Thanks, that "0000" helped